# How do I get a Java WebService to actually show me exceptions from the proxy object?

Tags: java, web-services, proxy

I'm chasing what should be a simple NullPointerException but a webservice proxy keeps swallowing the error.

The WS is exposed through a simple client library, that client then calls the WS. Somewhere in the WS theres an NPE and I can't find it because the stack trace only shows "$Proxy.someMethod" instead of the cause of the issue.

How can I get the stack trace from the proxy object? Is there a good strategy to log or handle these exceptions?

```
...
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:187)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:224)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:117)
******** I need the trace from this line *********
    at $Proxy43.myMethod(Unknown Source) 
*****************
    at com.mypackage.client.MyClient.aMethod(MyClient.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:161)
    ... 17 more
```

I've done some reading and it seems like this has to do with checked vs. unchecked exceptions. So if I were throwing an IOException I'd get the stack trace, but since there is a NullPointerException bubbling up its not giving me the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your service in a try/catch block and throw the exception that's defined as the fault element of the called service in your WSDL. That way the client will get a useable stacktrace.

Comment: We're in development/beta so its helpful to get a full stack trace in the client. Our testers can just send us the client error instead of sending us a useless trace, struggling mightily to give me a timestamp, then having my team go fishing through the logs.

Comment: @Freiheit - I've re-done my answer and checked that it works. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Sounds like it'll work. Accepted. That also takes me a step closer to returning useful error codes/messages versus just spewing out a stack trace.